# Syntax: ">" and "<" operators in java

Tags: java, syntax, integer

I was taking a look to java `java.lang.Integer` class and I noticed much methods with ">" and "<" operators but I don't know what are.

For example the method `Integer.signum(int i)`:

```
public static int signum(int i) {
    // HD, Section 2-7
    return (i >> 31) | (-i >>> 31);
}
```

Or `Integer.rotateLeft(int i, int distance)`

```
public static int rotateLeft(int i, int distance) {
    return (i << distance) | (i >>> -distance);
}
```

Comment: << (left shift) and >> (right shift)

Comment: Ok, I've found what are bitshifts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These operators perform a bitshift to the number.

`>>` bithshift right

`<<` bitshift left

Further information [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm) in the Bitwise Operators: section.

Comment: What is bitshift?

Comment: Shifting is taking the bits of a variable and shifting them to one of the sides asmany times as declared after the operator.

Comment: Having a `int` variable of lest say 5 which is represented as `00000101`, shifting it to the right once will produce `00000010`

Comment: Ok, thanks! I understand

Comment: Glad i could help, Please upvote and accept the answer, for the future lookers to come :)

Comment: Yes, I'm waiting to accept but for my reputation I can't upvote!

Comment: Thanks a lot, ill remind you again later if you forget , soon you'll be able to upvote too :)

Answer (score 0):

These are bit-shift operators.

More information in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) page.

Essentially:

- `<<` --> Signed left shift
- `>>` --> Signed right shift
- `>>>` --> Unsigned right shift

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work) SO question for elaborations on what bit-shifting operations are, and how they modify numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`>>` is arithmetic shift right, `>>>` is logical shift right and `<<` shift left.
for more details go to [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)